# How do I prevent jQuery full calendar from making round trips to the database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery full calendar with an ASP.NET MVC application.  My calendar will have between 600 and 3000 events throughout the year.  I return all events to the view from my controller, but when I change months my code makes the call to the database again.  I would like to either only call necessary events for the dates in view or reuse the data I have, unless there is an event that has a timestamp greater than the largest timestamp in the last view.  I am looking for a best practice / recommended approach.  If I go with the get events for dates in view only, how do I tell my ASP.NET MVC controller what days are in view ?

- Client Side:

  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
          getCalendar();
  });

  function getCalendar()
  {
          $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
              loading: function (bool) {

  ```
          },

          height: 500,

          dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
             },

          eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


          },

          dayRender: function (daysOfWeek, cell) {
              $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');

          },

          header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',

              right: 'month,agendaWeek'

          },
          editable: false,
          events: function (start, end, callback) {
              // UNDONE This should not be hard set
              var qs = Math.random();
              var url = '@Url.Action(@"GetJSONCalendarEvents")';
              url += "?rand=" + Math.random();

              url = decodeURIComponent(url);

              $.getJSON(url, function (locationsArray) {
                  var result = $(locationsArray).map(function () {
                      return {
                          id: this.id,
                          title: this.title,
                          start: this.start,
                          end: this.end,
                          allDay: this.editable,
                          className: this.className,
                          EventType: this.EventType
                      };
                  }).toArray();
                  callback(result);
              });
          },

          eventRender: function (event, element) {


          }
      });
  ```

  }

Comment: send start & end to server and only return events for that period. Or cache all your events after first call and use cache instead of making new request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call to the events data before init the fullCalendar and then pass to the events the data that you got.

```
$(document).ready(function () { $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 

var myData;

myData = function () {
        // UNDONE This should not be hard set
        var qs = Math.random();
        var url = '@Url.Action(@"GetJSONCalendarEvents")';
        url += "?rand=" + Math.random();

        url = decodeURIComponent(url);

        $.getJSON(url, function (locationsArray) {
            var result = $(locationsArray).map(function () {
                return {
                    id: this.id,
                    title: this.title,
                    start: this.start,
                    end: this.end,
                    allDay: this.editable,
                    className: this.className,
                    EventType: this.EventType
                };
            }).toArray();
            return result;
        });



getCalendar(myData); });

function getCalendar() { $("#calendar").fullCalendar({ loading: function (bool) {

    },

    height: 500,

    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
       },

    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


    },

    dayRender: function (daysOfWeek, cell) {
        $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');

    },

    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',

        right: 'month,agendaWeek'

    },
    editable: false,
    events: myData
    },

    eventRender: function (event, element) {


    }
});
}
```

Comment: although this would work, 6000 events is rather crazy to load when you may only need a 100.  Use full calendar AJAX calls, it will send 'start' and 'end' GET variables, use that to filter your results.  fullCalendar will then fetch only when needed.

Comment: Hi eyalib .  I can see the json data come back using your code example, but it never appears in the calendar.  What did I miss ?